# Sort values of multiple text columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
         A       B       C   D     E
0   apple  banana  orange   5  0.09
1  orange   apple  banana  10   4.0
2  banana  orange   apple  15   1.9
3  banana   apple  banana  20   2.8
```

I want to sort values of each row only based on column A,B,C as follows:

```
0   apple  banana  orange   5  0.09
1  apple   banana  orange  10   4.0
2  apple   banana   orange  15   1.9
3  apple   banana  banana  20   2.8
```

I have tried the solution like `df['F']=(df.A+df.B+df.C).map(set).map(list)` such that I can create a new column F and later replace A,B,C with the value of the splitted list of F, but it is concatinating all letters of my strings and creating a set ot of that, terefore of no use, as follows:

```
 A       B       C   D     E                            F
0   apple  banana  orange   5  0.09  [b, g, r, l, n, a, p, e, o]
1  orange   apple  banana  10   4.0  [b, g, r, l, n, a, p, e, o]
2  banana  orange   apple  15   1.9  [b, g, r, l, n, a, p, e, o]
3  banana   apple  banana  20   2.8           [b, l, n, a, p, e]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[['A','B','C']] = np.sort(df[['A','B','C']].to_numpy(), axis=1)
```

or

```
df[['A','B','C']] = [sorted(i) for i in df[['A','B','C']].to_numpy()]
```

Output:

```
       A       B       C   D     E
0  apple  banana  orange   5  0.09
3  apple  banana  banana  20  2.80
2  apple  banana  orange  15  1.90
1  apple  banana  orange  10  4.00
```

Comment: Just for the information: ```to_numpy()``` is added in pandas 0.24.0, so it does not work in previous versions of pandas.

Comment: Sorry.... I should have mentioned this you can use `.values` instead.